# Error with Alexa's API for domains without Alexa Rank

Tags: php, alexa-internet

I am using Alexa's API (the `URLInfo` function) to check the Alexa Rank of some domains. This works well for most URLs, however when I use a URL that is too new to have an alexa rank, it instead returns to me the alexa rank of the main domain.

For example, when checking `http://example.blogspot.com` or `http://example.wordpress.com`, etc, If the domain does not have an Alexa rank, it instead returns the Alexa rank of `http://wordpress.com` and `http://blogspot.com` respectively.

Is there any way to avoid this from happening?

Comment: [This link from Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14644/how-do-i-find-the-alexa-traffic-rank-of-a-site-that-uses-a-subdomain) might be able to tip you off.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if thats the same case, because if that were true, no blogger would ever be able to see the alexa rank of his/her site, unless they are separately hosted! Besides, it works perfectly for most `blogspot`,`wordpress`,etc. domains, just the ones that do not have an Alexa Rank, default the main domain's Rank instead